# JQuery search dom elements just after rendering and replace keys by its corresponding values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply my own localization method on my under development web application. 
knowing that I am using JQuery 2.2.0, without any other framework or third party. I need to write some expressions in my pure html code such that:

```
ex-1:
<span>#{{lang.details}}</span>

ex-2:
<button value='#{{lang.save}}'>
```

And then, once the dom is completely rendered, I want to pass through the dom element and find out all these expressions that start with "#{{" and end with "}}", to replace them with the corresponding value in my JSON bundle.

My JSON bundle looks like:

```
var en = {
    details: "details",
    save: "save"
}
```

My app.js code:

```
var lang = en;
// jquery load en json file
// search the dom elements and replace the key surrounded 
// by '#{{ }}' with its corresponding value from the bundle
```

What is the optimal way to find out these element either in JavaScript or in JQuery. I can't is there any other solution through a third party ?

Comment: Something like Handlebars or Mustache?

Comment: I'm thinking regex

Comment: Is `lang` the only variable that will be accessed this way?

Comment: I'm asking because I would like to avoid using `eval()` in my answer so that it can be more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replacing HTML with JavaScript Variables after Page Load

```
var doneReplacing = false;
$(function() {
    if (doneReplacing === false) {
        $(document.documentElement).html(function(index, content) {
            return content.replace(/#{{([^}]*)}}/g, function(match, $1) {
                return eval($1);
            });
        });
        doneReplacing = true;
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/4castle/jum3hmg5/2/)

[Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/aH7eR2/1)

Basically what it does is, after the page loads, it searches for the pattern `#{{ variable }}` and then replaces the match with the value of the variable.

Comment: I hope you find this helpful! If there are any ways to improve this answer, please do not hesitate to speak up. Creating this answer was a learning experience for me.

Comment: It's come to my attention that running the replace on the whole document reloads the document. So I made it check a variable to make sure that it doesn't run forever.

Comment: Is there any way to handle the issue without reloading the document ?

Comment: The best solution to that is to replace the `document.documentElement` part with the most narrow selector you can that still encompasses all the patterns. `document.body` might be a good place. Whatever is least encompassing. The reloading issue only happens if the javascript code itself is also within the part it searches. Then you can just remove all the `doneReplacing` stuff.

Comment: You could also just put the javascript in an external file so that it never gets interrupted by the reload.