# Change text with javascript and keep src

Tags: javascript, html, src

Sorry if it's a noob question !

I'm using a script to translate my page with this code:

```
<script>
        var translations= { 'en' : 
                                {'title' : 'Title', 'textimg' : 'English text'},
                            'fr' : 
                                {'title' : 'Titre', 'textimg' : 'Texte français'}
                          };
        function doTranslate(language) {
            for(id in translations[language]) {
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = translations[language][id];
            }
        }
</script>
```

And this html:

```
<a href="javascript:doTranslate('fr')"><img src="img/Fr-Flag.png"></a>
<a  href="javascript:doTranslate('en')"><img src="img/UK-Flag.png"></a>
<h2 id="title">Title</h2>
```

The problem comes when I use an image (little icon): the text changes, but `src` seems to disapear, so when the text change, the image is not displayed:

```
<img id="textimg" src="img/fav-rond.png">English text</img>
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: What is your expected output? Something like `English [x]` where `English` is some arbitrary translated text and `[x]` is the flag image?

Comment: I would like to have the image beside the changed text, like this:
`image` English text -> `image` Texte français

Comment: which text is changing and which id you are passing?

Comment: Maybe you should provide a more complete HTML of your current implementation, it seems a bit ambiguous now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this answer about content inside the `img` tags: [Div tag within img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425377/div-tag-within-img-tag)

But a possible solution is to remove the `id` from `img` and create a new element around the text with that id. For example:

```
<img src="img/fav-rond.png" />
<span id="textimg">English text</span>
```

And a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7j2ckw0r/1/

Comment: I have tried this, but the image is not beside the text

Comment: Make it `span` or use a little CSS

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue.

```
document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("id", translations[language][id])
```

You shouldn't be using innerHTML to solve this issue.

Comment: @SGS Venkatesh Your solution helped me to solve another problem (href) ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `<img>` tag does not allow any information within, it is a ["Empty element"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element)

If you add any text inside, that becomes an invalid HTML text.

What you can do is adding an `alt` attribute:

```
<img id="textimg" src="img/fav-rond.png" alt="English text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to visit this link, you will find the optimal way to translate your html page in pure JavaScript code.

[JQuery search dom elements just after rendering and replace keys by its corresponding values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159506/jquery-search-dom-elements-just-after-rendering-and-replace-keys-by-its-correspo)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to add text to an image tag, instead place a *span* element directly after the image and access that instead.

```
<img src="img/fav-rond.png" /><span id="textimg">English text</span>
```